# Make a timer fire at the end of each month c#

Tags: c#, timer

I need to make a timer fire at the end of each month.
I have written a small program that has code that needs to be executed at the last day of each month and I have no idea how to implement it. I suggested to my boss using windows scheduler but he wants it done in code with timer.

So how do I do this ?

Comment: Don't use a timer for this (even if your boss insists on it - it's totally stupid; timers are for seconds or minutes - not for once a month....). Use the Windows scheduled tasks functionality to launch your app once at every month's end...

Comment: Unless your boss hasn't got a clue, he might have a valid/good reason. Try to find out what that reason is; it will probably result in an other requirement that you are not aware of. (E.g.: He doesn't trust operations to maintain a scheduled task)

Comment: I would vote you a thousand times, but unfortunately I am still on a probationary period... ooops.

Comment: It is a simple mail server that will send emails, the timer itself will invoke a single function once a month, at the end of each month. I have written the small project as a windows service.

Comment: Dont do it with a timer man! This IS THE opportunity to let the boss know its not best practice and to provide some guarantee the service will work reliably that [Scheduled Tasks is build officially for this purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).  I'm pretty sure using a System.Timers.Timer in a scheduled task won't work, I think you may have to resort to `System.Threading.Timer`. Imagine that, a month timer done on a thread. 2.62974e9 milliseconds! Use @ErnodeWeerd's advice too. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with marc_s however if your boss insist, you can write a custom scheduler (http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or simply a timer  invoked once per day and check if is the last day of the month (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2478/C-Scheduler)

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for the responses. I persuaded the boss to use windows scheduled tasks. Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to persuade the boss to use windows scheduled tasks.  There is a way to do this with a timer. I include the code here below. It is quick and dirty. Note strongly that Using Scheduled tasks IS the correct way to implement this kind of task.

```
    private Timer timer;

    public MyClass()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {

        if (DateTime.Now.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month))// is it the last day of this month
        {
            ClientStatsController.FireAll();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        timer.Interval = CalculateInterval();
        TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)timer.Interval);

    }

    // Helper functions
    private static TimeSpan From24HourFormat(string value)
    {
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(0, 2));
        int mins = Convert.ToInt32(value.Substring(2, 2));

        return TimeSpan.FromHours(hours) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mins);
    }

    private double CalculateInterval()
    {
        string runtimeValue = ConfigController.AppSettings["runTime"]; // just a simple runtime string like 0800
        double runTime = From24HourFormat(runtimeValue).TotalMilliseconds;
        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds < runTime)
        {
            return runTime - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
        else
        {
            return (From24HourFormat("2359").TotalMilliseconds - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds) + runTime;
        }
    }
```

***EDIT***

I started going through all my older questions and answers.

Using a timer is a very bad idea. For scheduled tasks you want to use exaclty that. A scheduler. Windows provides a decent task scheduler, but if you have more complex scheduling logic and background tasks, it is better to use a proper third party library.

The two outstanding ones for .NET are Hangfire and Quartz.

Hangfire comes complete with a dashboard and is super easy to implement, especially if your working on the .NET core platform.

Quartz is also a very nice solution, and it has more scheduling options and better suited for complicated scheduling logic than Hangfire.

The proposed solution is indeed a very bad on, coming from an intern who just started working. I am happy to go back in time and realize how things can be done differently and better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way to get your job to run only on the last day of the month.

```
// Set timer to run every 24hrs
new Timer(RunJobMethod, null, 0, (int)TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Add the below piece of code to your RunJobMethod

```
// Enforce it only runs on the last day of the month
var currentMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
var nextMonth = currentMonth.AddMonths(1);
var lastDay = nextMonth.AddDays(-1);
if (DateTime.Now.Day != lastDay.Day || DateTime.Now.Month != lastDay.Month || DateTime.Now.Year != lastDay.Year)
    return;
```